# Best resources to learn origami art immediately?

Tags: origami

I saw one of my class fellows creating beautiful origami art work with paper. I was quite amazed, so I would like to learn origami art.

Can you provide resources or recommendations on how to learn origami art immediately?

Comment: Hi & welcome to Arts & Crafts. What would help your question is example pictures of the type of Origami Art you would like to learn and what access you have to books, internet, and also what sort of budget you have to spend on the resources.

Comment: he had made a lot of stars and fish and some cool animals, well i can afford art accessories at least and i like arts

Comment: Unfortunately, questions [asking for resources on learning an art or craft are not on-topic](https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com/q/183/30) for this site. There are just way too many "right" answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all crafts and arts, you can not expect to make beautiful items when you just start. You will have to start with the simple models and big sheets of paper. 
Once you have some experience, you will go up to more difficult patterns and smaller paper.

Depending on how you take to it, it might take days or weeks, but origami can be done beautiful with little experience when you work precise and with good paper.

Using a good book or a good website, cheap paper for your first few tries but nice paper for as soon as you are happy you can do the model. Depending on how you learn best, still pictures with how to fold, as in the books, or videos with fold along instructions will work. If you go for one style, try to get a site or person who has done more than just one or two, as while you are learning, following the same kind of instructions is often helpful. On the other hand, if you do not understand the instructions, other instructions for the same item may well help you.
Some websites, (I have no connection with any, I learned my folding from age 4, well before internet was invented.)
[Beginners as well as more advanced.](http://www.origami-instructions.com/simple-origami.html)
[Not as easy but clear indication which models are not starter ones.](https://www.origami-fun.com/origami-instructions.html)
You can say that all sites that make you fold a crane as first item are over ambitious.
I am out of the books, as the last one I purchased was 20 years back or so, but I know that if you go to a good bookshop, they should stock some. Look and read, buy a kid book if you can understand what the pictures instruct. You can go on to adult books after you have learned the basics.

There are also many youtube channels and individual videos dedicated to origami. Again I would suggest to start with instructions aimed at children.

While the boxes or packages with nice paper seem quite expensive, you will find that one pack will last quite a few models.

One way to make bigger results of small and relatively simple origami is to put them together and make scenes, birthday cards or pictures. Or to go modular, where you make the same piece over and over and put them together.

If you dream of big and intricate figures you will need to keep improving on what you have learned, using bigger and more difficult models. But do start with baby steps, and keep improving step by step. If you try to go too difficult before you have the basics, you may give up well before you are good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to make, YouTube is the best place to start as you can follow along with the YouTuber, I found it useful when I had a go.

Answer (score 1):

Art and craft stores usually have some books to sell. There are books specialized on origami animals or flowers or similar topics and books with a general theme and a mix of different origami figures. Usually you can buy origami paper in these stores as well, so you don't have to cut "regular" paper to the right size before folding origami. A [bone folder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bone_folder) is another very usefull tool you can find at art stores.

If there is no art store around where you live, go to a regular book store and look for the hobby and arts department. If all else fails, go to your favorite online book store.

You should have a look at the books to see if you understand the instructions. Most instructions are well-suited for beginners, but some might be hard to understand. One or two books should be enough for a lot of origami fun.

YouTube is the next best source of instructions with the added benefit of seeing how the paper is folded instead of reading and understanding instructions.

There are many different websites dedicated to origami and most offer some instructions for free and more advanced instructions for money only. Google for "origami instructions" and have a look at different sites (I can't really help you with this selection. It's best to try out different sites by yourself).

The advantage is that you can save bookmarks to your favorite sites or print instructions.

Answer (score -1):

What about craftsy.com or you tube ? Maybe deviant art.com?I'm unsure of whether or not deviant art has any instructional videos but they have plenty of inspiration. Pinterest could even be a place to look ?